# Send Alert Message For Invalid File Type Upload (Python)

Tags: python, upload, alert, dashboard, file-type

I'm making a dashboard application, and I want to use dash_bootstrap_components to show an alert message when a user attempts to upload a file which isn't a CSV.

This is what I have right now.

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1(children=''),

        # uploader
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload-data',
            children=html.Div([
                'Drag and Drop or ',
                html.A('Select Files'),
            ]),
            style={
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '60px',
                'lineHeight': '60px',
                'borderWidth': '1px',
                'borderStyle': 'dashed',
                'borderRadius': '5px',
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'margin': '10px'
            },
            # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
            multiple=True
        ),
        html.Div([
            dbc.Alert(
                "Unsuccessful Upload. Please make sure to upload a CSV file.",
                id='alert_message',
                color="warning",
                dismissable=True,
                is_open=False,
            ),
        ]),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output('alert_message', 'is_open'),
    [
        Input('upload-data', 'filename'),
    ]
)

def is_valid(filename, is_open):
    if 'csv' not in filename:
        return not is_open
    return is_open
```

When I run this, I get this error...

```
TypeError: is_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'is_open'
```

...and when I try to upload a file that is not a csv, no message is shown. How can I tweak this so that a user will see the alert message when they upload an inappropriate file?

Incidentally, I'm most likely going about checking the uploaded file type the wrong way. I looked up other methods for doing so, but they didn't seem to be compatible with using dbc alerts. If you know a better way of checking the file type, I'd love help with that too. But my main concern is getting the alert to show up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about the error message?

Comment: It's not necessarily that I don't understand the error message, I'm just sharing what happens when I run this code. I can only assume the error is happening because 'is_open" isn't getting passed to the function. Do I need to add a "State" to the callback for that?

Comment: I don’t know, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: It worked!

```
@app.callback(Output('alert_message', 'is_open'),
 [Input('upload-data', 'filename')],
    [State("alert_message", "is_open")],
)
```

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that the message shows up even if I upload a CSV...